# Acesso https no AWS não funciona

Tags: linux, amazon-aws, certificado-digital, https

Estou tentando configurar HTTPS ao usuário final numa instância EC2 no AWS Linux.
Até comprei o certificado pelo RapidSSL e segui os passos para tentar liberar manualmente o acesso, mas não consegui.

Então configurei o Load Balance para esta instância e tentei usar o meu certificado e também o certificado requerido da própria Amazon. Porém, é exibido "OutOfService" na aba **Instances** para minha instância (desde ontem, quando configurei).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E na aba **Description**, exibe que o Status é "0 of 1 instances in service".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo ter feito de errado? E como posso corrigir?

**EDITADO**

Alterei a configuração da aba **Healthy Check**, apontando para a porta HTTP - 80 (estava usando a porta HTTPS - 443 antes) e os valores foram modificados:

1. Em Description, exibe que o Status é "1 of 1 instances in service"
2. Em Instances, exibe o Status "InService"

Porém, o objetivo continua não funcionando: o site deve ser acessado como www.meusite.com e exibir *https://www.meusite.com* (conexão segura). Mas não está acessando dessa forma, e nem se digitar https (daí não encontra o site!).
Como fazer?

Comment: Qual servidor esta usando Apache, Nginx ou outro? Porque em geral você precisa configurar os certificado e as rotas dentro deles também, além de alterar algumas coisas dentro da "Rota 53", eu suponho que seja Apache então de uma lida nesse link: [Tutorial: Configure Apache Web Server on Amazon Linux to use SSL/TLS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html)

Comment: Sim, estou usando Apache. Pelo que vi, em teoria este tutorial trata da configuração tal como é feita sem o uso do Load Balancer e do ACM Certificate da Amazon, certo? Quero dizer, se tenho os certificados da RapidSSL, eu poderia seguir este tutorial para finalizar minha configuração sem o uso dos recursos mencionados, é isso?

Comment: Tem certeza que não é problema de DNS? Que servidor de DNS você utiliza? Route 53 ou outro, tipo onde você registrou o domínio? Se você der `ping www.meusite.com` aparece o IP do seu load balancer?

Comment: No Security Group existe a regra de liberação da porta 443?

Comment: Se seus servidores estiverem em uma VPC, talvez o melhor seja verificar as regras [ACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html).